# What is the correct way to define and query a 3NF Associative entity

Tags: mysql, linux

A subset of my database contains the tables contacts, networks and networkContacts which is my associative entity. I have defined it using a composite primary key composed of the primary keys of the first two tables. The tables are are defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (
  cid char(88) NOT NULL,
  alias varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cid)
)

CREATE TABLE networks (
  nid int(11) NOT NULL,
  fingerprint char(88) NOT NULL,
  port int(11) NOT NULL,
  network_alias varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (nid),
  UNIQUE KEY fingerprint (fingerprint),
  UNIQUE KEY port (port),
  UNIQUE KEY network_alias (network_alias)
)

CREATE TABLE networkContacts (
  nid int(11) NOT NULL,
  cid char(88) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (nid,cid),
  CONSTRAINT networkContacts_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (nid) REFERENCES networks (nid),
  CONSTRAINT networkContacts_ibfk_2 FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES contacts (cid)
)
```

Is this correct and if so how should I correctly query the contacts table by inner joining it with the networks table as every example I have seen uses both fields in the primary key to conduct the join. As you can see I only have one field of the associative entity primary key in each of the other tables respectively so doing a join based on both components can't be done.

Comment: 4 unique keys in a 4 column table?  This seems quite unreasonable.

Comment: The nid is the primary key so it must be unique, fingerprint must be unique being a hash of a public key where each network has a distinct set of keys, the port must obviously be different for each network and the network_alias must be different to allow humans to differentiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `JOIN` `contacts` to `networks` you need to first `JOIN` to `networkContacts`.

```sql
select *
from contacts a
    inner join networkContacts b
        on a.cid=b.cid
    inner join networks c
        on c.nid=b.nid
```

Comment: Alright thanks, I thought it might be bad form to perform individual joins based on just part of the primary key but great

Comment: The PK on `networkContacts` is there to prevent duplicate pairs of `(nid,cid)` within the table.  It could just as easily be a `UNIQUE` constraint (since the columns are defined as `NOT NULL`)